# Gitlab Backup and "Unable to to verify certificate"

Tags: ssl, gitlab, gitlab-ci, excon

In our Ubuntu server, an ex-partner has installed our Gitlab. I have no experience with gitlab. Now, I want to create a backup.

After running

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create
```

I get the following error:

> Uploading backup archive to remote storage smartupgitlab ... rake
>   aborted! Excon::Errors::SocketError: Unable to verify certificate,
>   please set `Excon.defaults[:ssl_ca_path] = path_to_certs`,
>   `ENV['SSL_CERT_DIR'] = path_to_certs`, `Excon.defaults[:ssl_ca_file] =
>   path_to_file`, `ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = path_to_file`,
>   `Excon.defaults[:ssl_verify_callback] = callback` (see
>   OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext#verify_callback), or
>   `Excon.defaults[:ssl_verify_peer] = false` (less secure).

I guess I must use the indicated lines of code, but in what file exactly should I paste them?

Comment: Check your `gitlab.rb`. Is `gitlab_rails['backup_upload_remote_directory']` set?

Comment: Yes it is, "gitlab_rails['backup_upload_remote_directory'] = 'smartupgitlab'.
Seems it can't find it?

Comment: Comment it out and rerun your command again. Backup location is stored in the Config value `gitlab_rails['backup_path']`. `smartupgitlab` doesn't seem to be a valid location.

Comment: I forgot. If you make changes to the config you need to run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

Comment: @Fairy now I get ArgumentError: bucket_name is required. Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: `gitlab_rails['backup_upload_connection']` should be commented out aswell. GitLab is telling us that it can't find the key we just commented out.

Comment: The backup was made. I have some other problems now, but you answered this question, thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked! Feel free to ask anytime if another problem arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup upload to a remote location is configured on your installation. The location specified doesn't exist however. Commenting out  `gitlab_rails['backup_path']` and `gitlab_rails['backup_upload_connection']` should make it work again. Once commented out run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and local backups should work again.